# How to print out result data in a table cell (and not on the same row) using Axios and vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, axios

I want to be able to print out the next three upcoming train departure time, arrival time and train number when using Axios in JavaScript in a table that I have created with HTML.

I do get the output result after I have typed in the city name in the search bar and clicked search. However, the problem is that I get the output for  the next upcoming train numbers in the same table cell, and same issue happens with the departure and arrival time as you can see down below in the image link.

**[Output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRZxV.jpg)**

I have tried changing the CSS using display: flex; but it doesn't work. I have even tried hard coding the array index using 0, 1, 2 instead of i and removed the for-loop but then the output result will only show one of the latest train departure time, arrival time and train number, and not all three of them at the same time which is what I wish to have, which is like this:

```
  Trainnr:              Departure      Arrival
  Regional Tåg 971      19:11:00       19:48:00
  Regional Tåg 863      19:21:00       19:53:00
  Länstrafik - Tåg 40   19:26:00       20:25:00
```

**This is my code in the HTML for the train table:**

```
<section class="trainSchedule">
  <strong><p class="train-title">Railway Time Table</p></strong>
  <div class="box">
    Does the train go to Stockholm?
    <br />
    I'm departing from..

    <input type="text" class="request-input" placeholder="Ex: Göteborg" />
    <button class="request-btn">Search...</button>
    <div class="message-box">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="trainNumber">TrainNr:</th>
            <th class="departure">Departure:</th>
            <th class="arrival">Arrival:</th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="trainNum"></td>
            <td class="trainDep"></td>
            <td class="trainArr"></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
    Departing from: <strong><div class="response-result"></div></strong>
  </div>
</section>
```

And here is vanilla JavaScript code using axios:

```
let reqBtn = document.querySelector(".request-btn");
let reqInput = document.querySelector(".request-input");
let respResult = document.querySelector(".response-result");

const API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const DEST_ID_FIXED = "740000001";

function getOriginIdURL(city, key) {
  return `https://api.resrobot.se/v2.1/location.name?input=${city}&format=json&accessId=${key}`;
}

function getRouteURL(originId, destId, key) {
  return `https://api.resrobot.se/v2.1/trip?format=json&originId=${originId}&destId=${destId}&passlist=true&showPassingPoints=true&accessId=${key}`;
}

function findRoute(fromCity) {
  let searchURL = getOriginIdURL(fromCity, API_KEY);

  axios.get(searchURL).then((response) => {
    let data = response.data;
    let originId = data.stopLocationOrCoordLocation[0].StopLocation.extId;

    let routeURL = getRouteURL(originId, DEST_ID_FIXED, API_KEY);

    axios.get(routeURL).then((response) => {
      let data = response.data;
      // console.log(response.data.Trip[0].LegList.Leg[0].Product[0].name);

    
     let trainNum = document.querySelector(".trainNum");
     let trainDep = document.querySelector(".trainDep");
     let trainArr = document.querySelector(".trainArr");


       for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

      trainNum.textContent += "\n" + data.Trip[i].LegList.Leg[0].Product[0].name;
    

      trainDep.textContent += "\n" + data.Trip[i].Origin.time;
   

      trainArr.textContent += "\n" + data.Trip[i].Destination.time;



       let table = document.querySelector('table');
       
       let tr = document.createElement('tr'); 
       let tr2 = document.createElement('td');
       let tr3 = document.createElement('td');
       let tr4 = document.createElement('td');

       tr2 = trainNum.textContent;
       tr3 = trainDep.textContent;
       tr4 = trainArr.textContent;

      // tr.append(tr2, tr3, tr4);
       table.append(tr);


    
       } 

      respResult.textContent = `${reqInput.value}`;
   
      // console.log(data.Trip[0].Origin.time);
      // console.log(data.Trip[1].Origin.time);
      // console.log(data.Trip[2].Destination.name);
      // console.log("");

    });
  });
}

reqBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

  findRoute(reqInput.value);

});
```

What am I doing wrong here?
I really appreciate if anyone can help me out and explain.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just re-writing the part where you process the `response`, because I think that's the only part of interest here. Basically, you should create your new row (`<tr>`) and your new cells (`<td>`) before to add content to them. And then you set the text content of them. And then you append the row to the table.

```
axios.get(routeURL).then((response) => {
      let data = response.data;
      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      
        let newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        let trainNumCell = document.createElement("td");
        trainNumCell.classList.add("trainNum");
        newRow.append(trainNumCell);
        let trainDepCell = document.createElement("td")
        trainDepCell.classList.add("trainDep")
        newRow.append(trainDepCell);
        let trainArrCell = document.createElement("td")
        trainArrCell.classList.add("trainArr")
        newRow.append(trainArrCell);
        
        trainNumCell.textContent = data.Trip[i].LegList.Leg[0].Product[0].name;
        trainDepCell.textContent = data.Trip[i].Origin.time;
        trainArrCell.textContent = data.Trip[i].Destination.time;

        let table = document.querySelector('table');
        table.append(newRow);
     } 

     respResult.textContent = `${reqInput.value}`;
});
```

Concerning the HTML, you could simplify it, you don't to pre-create a row. So you table could be only this

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="trainNumber">TrainNr:</th>
        <th class="departure">Departure:</th>
        <th class="arrival">Arrival:</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works now just as I wanted. I am new to web development and I kinda had a feeling it would be something simple like that but I still could not understand what it was. This will definitely help me for future projects. I appreciate it a lot!